# Whence for Windows?

Tags: windows, troubleshooting, path

I'm trying to determine the location of an executable (java.exe) on Windows.  I know it must exist somewhere in the PATH since I can run it, but I don't know the exact directory that it is being run from.  On a UNIX system I could use the whence command to obtain this information.  Is there an equivalent command for Windows systems?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On my Vista laptop if I type "where java.exe" from the command prompt it gives me the location of java.exe.

Hope this helps.

Comment: "where" works on Windows 2003 and Win 7 too. Does not appear to be part of XP though.

Comment: where.exe can be copied directly from a 2003 box to an XP box and will work fine there.  just do "where where.exe" to locate it!

Comment: @mh It's in C:\Windows\System32 on my machine.  Running "where where" (no extension is needed) finds it.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly. You have a few choices:

- At a command prompt from the root of C: run: Dir /s java.exe
- install the win32 port of which.exe (there may be a whence.exe port too)
- use the search functionality in windows explorer
- get one of several third party windows file indexing and searching utilities

Comment: The dir /s is a good option; the output can then be cross-referenced with the PATH contents.

Answer (score 1):

Install this:
http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/which.htm
Then open a command prompt and type: `which java`

Comment: You may need to add the directory where you installed which to your PATH.

Answer (score 0):

In a command prompt type "path".... that will give you your path you can also use the "find" command.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the first Google hit for "[equivalent whence windows](http://www.google.com/search?q=equivalent+whence+windows)".  You'll have to write a small utility to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a "whereis" script from Raymond Chen's blog:

http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2005/01/20/357225.aspx